# The problem with community wiki

Tags: support, accepted-answer, community-wiki

This is not a great problem. While poking into a question yesterday, I thought I might answer (as it didn't get a lot of attention though). Today (I mean, NOW) I see my post [under "community wiki"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/44174). I saw the revision history specifically saying, "Post made community wiki by Crazy Buddy". I haven't done anything as such. I must agree that I try to "type in" fast.

- Is there any keyboard letter that triggers community wiki or could anyone trigger it except me?
- I know that community wiki votes are earned by the "-1" user. Would the *accepted answer* vote also goes to him?

Nothing special with that question and my answer though. Just a curiosity (maybe for later use - *like that*) But, I have a suspicion that I would've done something *crazy*. Machines don't lie. Do they? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wiki flag removed.

It seems likely that you accidental clicked the community wiki check box on the edit screen.

---

However, be aware that too many edits will force a post in wiki mode.

I think that the threshold is currently 10 *logged* revisions (there is a five minute grace period under which revisions are lumped together as one for this purpose).

Comment: Thank you dmckee. I see now. Moderators also have control over the community wiki mode. *Man, Good for me* :-)